# Tooltip does not Label plotted variables

Tags: plotting, labeling

```
lmax=5.8;a=.804;
NDSolve[{PH'[l]==X[l]^2/a^3,PH[0]==0.,AR'[l]==Y[l] Cos[PH[l]],Y'[l]==Sin[PH[l]],Y[0]==0.,X'[l]==Cos[PH[l]],X[0]==0.,AR[0]==0},{PH,X,Y,AR},{l,0,lmax}];
{ph[u_],x[u_],y[u_],ar[u_]}={PH[u],X[u],Y[u],AR[u]}/.First[%];
ParametricPlot[{x[l],y[l]},{l,0,lmax}];
Plot[Tooltip[{ph[l],ar[l],  x  [l],y[l] }],{l,0,lmax}]
```

I prefer the Tootip to read labels ph,ar, x,y as named  but not again echo the same "Interpolating Function" [...]

Comment: Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[#[l], #] & /@ {ph, ar, x, y}], {l, 0, lmax}]

Comment: Thanks Bob, no more living with this problem !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
flist = {ph, ar, x, y};
```

The most straightforward approach is the one suggested by @Bob Hanlon in the comments section: `Plot[Tooltip[#@l, #] & /@ flist, {l, 0, lmax}, Evaluated -> True]`.

The following unusual usage of the option `PlotStyle` also gives the desired result:

```
Plot[Through@flist@l, {l, 0, lmax}, Evaluated -> True, Filling -> Axis,
 PlotStyle -> (Function[t, Tooltip[#, t] &] /@ flist)]
```

[image]

You can also add tooltips via post-processing:

```
Block[{j = 1}, Plot[Through@flist@l, {l, 0, lmax}, Evaluated -> True, Filling -> Axis] /. 
      Line[x_] :> Tooltip[Line[x], flist[[j++]]]]
(* same picture *)
```

Comment: Arrow position does not cycle,( my Ver8?)